# Define a workbook based on name defined in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

- I want to define a second Workbook's data so it can be selected by another macro by using a name defined in the cell A1 from the active workbook.
- Cell A1 has the text "openme"

I currently have:

```
Sub CrossCopyRangeSelect()

Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("A1").Value

Set x = ThisWorkbook
Set y = Workbooks(Filename:=Range("A1").Value)

End Sub
```

There is an error at

```
Set y =
```

And I'm unsure which function to be using to define the workbook name from the text in A1

Comment: On a re-read, does A1 have a filepath or a macro to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have opened the new book, it becomes the **active** book:

```
Sub CrossCopyRangeSelect()
    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set x = ThisWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Range("A1").Value
    Set y = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub
```

NOTE:

I have the full filespec in cell **A1**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you may need to remove the file's path from the name in the `set y = workbooks(name)` statement.

The easiest fix for your code is to assign y right at the open statement:

```
Set y = Workbooks.Open(Range("A1").Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner to check if the file actually exists before opening it:

```
Sub CrossCopyRangeSelect()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook

    Set Wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    If Len(Dir(Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value)) > 0 Then
        Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value)
    Else
        MsgBox "file doesnt exist"
    End If

End Sub
```